# JOGL and Snow leopard

Tags: java, macos, osx-snow-leopard, jogl

I'm having some major issues with getting JOGL to work on snow leopard.

I've installed all the necessary JOGL jars in

```
/system/library/java/extensions
```

I can get sample code to compile but when I attempt to run it it throws the error following error on trying to actually display the window.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize JAWT 
at com.sun.nativewindow.impl.jawt.JAWT$1.run(JAWT.java:100)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.nativewindow.impl.jawt.JAWT.getJAWT(JAWT.java:95)
at com.sun.nativewindow.impl.jawt.macosx.MacOSXJAWTWindow.lockSurface(MacOSXJAWTWindow.java:65)
at com.sun.opengl.impl.GLDrawableImpl.lockSurface(GLDrawableImpl.java:144)
at com.sun.opengl.impl.macosx.cgl.MacOSXCGLDrawable.setRealizedImpl(MacOSXCGLDrawable.java:87)
at com.sun.opengl.impl.GLDrawableImpl.setRealized(GLDrawableImpl.java:120)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.addNotify(GLCanvas.java:413)
at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2622)
at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:662)
at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:470)
at java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:858)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1563)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1515)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:841)
at SimpleJOGL.main(SimpleJOGL.java:45)
```

Has anyone seen this error before and if they have how did you fix it?

Regards

James

EDIT: This error appears using both Java 1.5 and Java 1.6 and I've tried JOGL beta 5, beta 10 and the nightly builds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What build of JOGL are you using, and what version of Java (1.5 or 1.6)?  There was some talk of the beta 5 release having this issue.  I found this link.  It's a shot in the dark but without more information it's all I have.

[JOGL Kenai Link](http://kenai.com/projects/jogl/forums/forum/topics/1379-Problem-with-beta5)

I was able to download a version of JOGL from the following link

[JOGL JSR 231 Beta 10](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-2.0-beta10/)

I downloaded the mac universal zip and was able to get it working by putting the jars on the classpath and pointing the java.library.path to the the directory I unzipped the archive to.  The archive includes all of the .so files you need to get JOGL running.  I don't think you need all of the jars included here.  There seem to be a lot of files related to the CDC, which I think is a mobile platform if memory serves.  I didn't include these in my test.

I didn't get the error you mentioned and am running Snow Leopard on a Core Duo MacBook Pro.  The used the source from the Gears demo and it ran without a hitch.  I even switched out the Frame with a JFrame to see if that would change anything.  It worked fine both ways.  You may want to try with this library and see if that works for you.

Comment: I've added the information to the original post, I found that link but it doesn't actually include any way of fixing it